# How to RegularExpressionValidator check digit 0-9 and "/" and "-" and ","

Tags: c#, regex, html, visual-studio

How to RegularExpressionValidator check digit 0-9 and "/" and "-" and ","

**Html**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPer" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="zorunlu" Display="Dynamic" ID="rangevalidator1" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtPer" ErrorMessage="Please Input Correct Format." ValidationExpression="^\d{8}$|^\d{17}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**Ex Format**

01/2015,05/2015-12/2015 >>> True

01/2015,05/2015aa-_12/2015qwe >>> False

Thanks advance ;)

Comment: So should `01/2015` be valid??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ValidationExpression should be as below:

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9\/\-,]*$"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO3eS6/1)

Comment: Since it was not detecting end of line as $ so it was not matching.

Comment: even `^[0-9/\-,]*` works there. But not  in the other site. Crazy

Comment: Thanks @Rahul It's Working! ^^

Answer (score 1):

u might use the following regex `^[0-9\/,-]*$`

> breakdown 
>  `0-9` numbers 
>  `\/` the / is a escape character so it needs a \ in front of it to make the regex know you mean the / not as an escape char  
>  `,` speaks for itself just the , 
> `-` the - at the end so that its not used as a from - till character but as the minus it self

for a test see https://regex101.com/r/sN3qY0/1

Answer (score 0):

Try Below ValidationExpression

```
^(?!.*,$|.*\d{2,})(?:([\d*#]),?(?!.*\1))+$
```